# Syntax Code to Retrieve Data from API to Class do not working properly

Tags: c#, xml, api, visual-studio-2013

I cannot retrieve the value of annonsid, annonsrubic etc from the API into the class annons. I don't know what part or syntax I'm missing.

```
   private static List<annons> myListAnnons = new List<annons>();     

    private static annons _myAnnons = new annons();

    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", " en-US");
        client.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/xml");
        client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)");

        xml = XDocument.Parse(client.DownloadString("http://api.arbetsformedlingen.se/af/v0/platsannonser/6309046");

    }


    xml.Root.Descendants("platsannons").ToList().ForEach(li =>
    {
        annons _myAnnons = new annons();
        _myAnnons.annonsid = li.Element("annonsid").Value;
        _myAnnons.annonsrubrik = li.Element("annonsrubrik").Value;
        _myAnnons.annonstext = li.Element("annonstext").Value;
        _myAnnons.antal_platser = li.Element("antal_platser").Value;
        _myAnnons.antalplatserVisa = li.Element("antalplatserVisa").Value;
        _myAnnons.arbetsplatsnamn = li.Element("arbetsplatsnamn").Value;
        _myAnnons.arbetstid = li.Element("arbetstid").Value;
        _myAnnons.arbetstidvaraktighet = li.Element("arbetstidvaraktighet").Value;
        _myAnnons.besoksadress = li.Element("besoksadress").Value;
        _myAnnons.egenbil = li.Element("egenbil").Value;
        _myAnnons.epostadress = li.Element("epostadress").Value;
        _myAnnons.hemsida = li.Element("hemsida").Value;
        _myAnnons.kommunnamn = li.Element("kommunnamn").Value;
        _myAnnons.land = li.Element("land").Value;
        _myAnnons.logotypurl = li.Element("logotypurl").Value;
        _myAnnons.loneform = li.Element("loneform").Value;
        _myAnnons.lonetyp = li.Element("lonetyp").Value;
        _myAnnons.namn = li.Element("namn").Value;
        _myAnnons.postadress = li.Element("postadress").Value;
        _myAnnons.postland = li.Element("postland").Value;
        _myAnnons.postnummer = li.Element("postnummer").Value;
        _myAnnons.postort = li.Element("postort").Value;
        _myAnnons.publiceraddatum = li.Element("publiceraddatum").Value;
        _myAnnons.referens = li.Element("referens").Value;
        _myAnnons.sista_ansokningsdag = li.Element("sista_ansokningsdag").Value;
        _myAnnons.telefonnummer = li.Element("telefonnummer").Value;
        _myAnnons.titel = li.Element("titel").Value;
        _myAnnons.varaktighet = li.Element("varaktighet").Value;
        _myAnnons.webbplats = li.Element("webbplats").Value;
        _myAnnons.yrkesbenamning = li.Element("yrkesbenamning").Value;
        _myAnnons.yrkesid = li.Element("yrkesid").Value;

        myListAnnons.Add(_myAnnons);
    });




    public class annons
    {
        public String annonsid;
        public String annonsrubrik;
        public String annonstext;
        public String yrkesbenamning;
        public String yrkesid;
        public String publiceraddatum;
        public String antal_platser;
        public String kommunnamn;
        public String antalplatserVisa;
        public String varaktighet;
        public String arbetstid;
        public String arbetstidvaraktighet;
        public String lonetyp;
        public String loneform;
        public String referens;
        public String webbplats;
        public String epostadress;
        public String sista_ansokningsdag;
        public String arbetsplatsnamn;
        public String postnummer;
        public String postadress;
        public String postort;
        public String postland;
        public String land;
        public String besoksadress;
        public String logotypurl;
        public String hemsida;
        public String namn;
        public String titel;
        public String telefonnummer;
        public String egenbil;
    }
```

Comment: The URL in your code doesn't match your class structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code

```
xml.Root.Descendants("platsannons").ToList()...
```

gives an empty list. `"platsannons"` is the name of the **root** element you already have. Your code tries to find **descendants** with this name - and has to fail.

It works if you replace it with

```
xml.Root.Descendants().ToList()...
```